# wx HtmlEasyPrinting encoding issues when Printing

Tags: python, wxwidgets

I have an html text with non-ascii characters, and I want it printed using HtmlEasyPrinting module.

```
printer = HtmlEasyPrinting()
text = '''
    <html>
    <head>
          <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    </head>
    <body>
         <b>&lt;</b>
         <p>&#233;</p>
    </body>
    </html>'''

printer.PreviewText(text)
printer.PrintText(text)
```

When I run the preview part, everything looks ok! (right encoding applied)
When I try to PrintText instead, things go wrong and it seems that non-ascii characters got funny representations on paper/exported file.

Anyone have an idea why the Preview works ok, but not the Printing itself? Are there some setting to be applied?

wx.version = 2.8.11.0 (gtk2-unicode)
python 2.7